# vimgrep case insensitive file pattern

Tags: vim, vimgrep

I use the following vimgrep command:

```
lv /pattern/ ./**/partoffilename*.coffee
```

as you already know we can add `\c` anywhere in the `pattern` to search case insensitively:

```
lv /pattern\c/ ./**/partoffilename*.coffee
```

but that doesn't work for file name pattern:

```
lv /pattern\c/ ./**/partoffilename*\c.coffee     <- won't work
```

So the question is how can I force vimgrep to search case insensitively not just in file content but in file names as well (i.e. to search not just in partoffilename*.coffee but also in PartOfFileName*.coffee, partOfFileName*.coffee, ...) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, in you need to set the `'wildignorecase'` option and make sure, that the 'fileignorecase' option is not set.

Comment: Just tested and with wildignorecase option set :lv /.*/ ./sectionconfig.coffee doesn't find anything though I can clearly see that SectionConfig.coffee file exists in current dir. And yes fileignorecase is not set (output of :set doesn't show that option).

Comment: Hm, you are missing a globbing character to make that option take effect. Try something like `?ection?onfig.coffee` or similar

Comment: Thanks, lv /.*/ ./?ection?onfig.coffee works fine, and yes this answers my question though I expected that vimgrep by itself supports some option to ignore case in file name or even path pattern.